# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. Array

Tags: c#, array, nullpointerexception

Oi, Meu problema é no array seguindo esse código:

```
mesh meshCube;
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines("object.mind");
foreach (string filetext in file)
{
    if (filetext.Contains("v"))
    {
        string ext = filetext.Substring(filetext.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
        string[] pos = ext.Split(' ');
        // erro nessa linha ↓
        meshCube.tris.Add( new triangle (
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[1]), float.Parse(pos[2])),
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[3]), float.Parse(pos[4]), float.Parse(pos[5])),
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[6]), float.Parse(pos[7]), float.Parse(pos[8])))
        );
     }
}

public class vec3d
{
    public vec3d(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public float z { get; set; }
}
public class triangle
{
    public triangle(vec3d one, vec3d two, vec3d three)
    {
        p = new[] { one, two, three };
    }
    public vec3d[] p = new vec3d[3];
}
public class mesh
{
    public List<triangle> tris = new List<triangle>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você declarou a variável `meshCube` mas não carregou a variável com nenhum objeto, por isso dá o erro `NullPointerException` ao tentar usa-la:

```
mesh meshCube;

// [...]

        // erro nessa linha ↓
        meshCube.tris.Add( new triangle (
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[1]), float.Parse(pos[2])),
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[3]), float.Parse(pos[4]), float.Parse(pos[5])),
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[6]), float.Parse(pos[7]), float.Parse(pos[8])))
        );
```

Declare dessa forma que deve resolver **esse** problema:

```
mesh meshCube = new mesh();
```

Vale mencionar que seria interessante verificar se o array `pos` contém a quantidade de itens necessária **antes** de usa-lo:

```
if (filetext.Contains("v"))
{
    string ext = filetext.Substring(filetext.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
    string[] pos = ext.Split(' ');
    // Verifica se o array contém a quantidade adequada de itens.
    if (pos.Length == 9)
    {
        meshCube.tris.Add( new triangle (
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[0]), float.Parse(pos[1]), float.Parse(pos[2])),
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[3]), float.Parse(pos[4]), float.Parse(pos[5])),
            new vec3d(float.Parse(pos[6]), float.Parse(pos[7]), float.Parse(pos[8])))
        );
    }
```

Porque isso pode causar outros erros também.